# Trying to keep player class from falling through ground class using colllision detection pygame

Tags: pygame, collision

As of now i have a player class that has gravity inact on it for every update method, right now all my gravity method does is check if the player is colliding with the ground, and if it is not colliding then the players yVel += 1, but is never more than 13 (never falls more than 13 pixels per frame) but the problem is if my player is right above the ground and falls (13) pixels to the ground, he is stuck in the middle of the ground and cannot jump back out. Is there any way i can fix this or do i need to completely re-write everything in my player class?

```
    import pygame
import time  # lint:ok
from pygame.locals import *

char = 'ball.png'
char_jump = 'ball_jump.png'

ball = pygame.image.load(char)
ballJump = pygame.image.load(char_jump)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, image, xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, checkGroup):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.xPos = xPos
        self.yPos = yPos
        self.xVel = xVel
        self.yVel = yVel
        self.image = image
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.isInAir = True
        self.checkGroup = checkGroup

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.gravity()
        self.xPos += self.xVel  # updates x and y based on velocities
        self.yPos += self.yVel  # updates rect
        self.rect.topleft = (self.xPos, self.yPos)  # updates sprite rectangle

        if self.xPos > 440:  # keeps player from going to far right and left
            self.xPos = 440
        if self.xPos < -3:  # #########
            self.xPos = -3

    def gravity(self):
        if self.checkCollision(self.checkGroup) is True:
            self.yVel = 0
        elif self.checkCollision(self.checkGroup) is False:
            self.yVel = 50

    def jump(self):
        if self.isInAir is False:
            print('jump')
            self.yVel -= 20
            self.image = ballJump

    def moveRight(self):
        self.xVel = 3

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.xVel = -3

    def stopLeft(self):
        self.xVel = 0
        self.image = ball

    def stopRight(self):
        self.xVel = 0
        self.image = ball

    def stopJump(self):
        self.image = ball
        if self.yVel < 0:  # if player is still jumping up
            self.yVel = 1  # make y Velocity positive (fall down)

    def checkCollision(self, group):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, group):
            return True
        elif not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, group):
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your collision checks are redundant:

```
def checkCollision(self, group):
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, group):
        return True
    elif not pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, group):
        return False
```

calls `spritecollideany` twice if there's no collision. You could just use:

```
def checkCollision(self, group):
    return pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, group)
```

---

Same for

```
def gravity(self):
    if self.checkCollision(self.checkGroup) is True:
        self.yVel = 0
    elif self.checkCollision(self.checkGroup) is False:
        self.yVel = 50
```

it can be rewritten as

```
def gravity(self):
    self.yVel = 0 if self.checkCollision(self.checkGroup) else 50
```

---

Now to your problem:

You check if your player collides with something, and if so, you just stop moving. This leads to the problem you described because you don't check for collision for every pixel you move, but only for each nth pixel, where n is your travelling speed. A common approach is to use something that is called CCD (continuous collision detection), but this is out of scope of this answer.

An easier approach is the following:

First check for collisions of the x-axis, then for collisions of the y-axis. If you register a collision, detect what object caused the collision. Then alter the position of the player to be on top of that object. You can find a complete example [here](http://www.nandnor.net/?p=64).

```
def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                ...
                if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top # <- relevant line
                    ...
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0: self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
```

If you have a simple game, this is a good-enough approach most of the time.